# Select from 2 Tables using Like and Not Like

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables in my database. 
Table1 consist of Work_ID, Actual_Work_Date.
Table2 consist of Work_ID, Scheduled_Date.

There is a case below:

**Table1**

> **Work_ID** | **Actual_Work_Date**
>
> 10000       | 2014-02-25
>
> 10001       | 2014-02-13

**Table2**

> **Work_ID** | **Scheduled_Date**
>
> 10000 | 2014-01-10
>
> 10000 | 2014-03-01
>
> 10001 | 2014-01-22
>
> 10001 | 2014-02-13

For `Work_ID=10000`, we failed to perform the work as per the first schedule (2014-01-10), so we re-schedule become `2014-03-01`.
But some how we can manage to do the work on 2014-02-25.

In my website, I want to view list of work that is not scheduled in this month but was performed in this month. How to make such list to show only Work_ID = 10000 without showing Work_ID = 10001?
I did the below but not working:

```
$query = "
    SELECT a.Work_ID 
    FROM Table1 a, Table2 b 
    WHERE a.Actual_Work_Date LIKE '2014-02%' 
        AND b.Scheduled_Date NOT LIKE '2014-02%' 
        AND a.Work_ID = b.Work_ID ";
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: hey what you want exactly,.. i think you wants to display like as `10000 | 2014-03-01`

Comment: Yes, I want to show list of Work_ID that is scheduled in the month other than 02-2014, but with Actual_Work_Date in the month of 02-2014. Using my script above it also shows Work_ID 10001, because it is once scheduled in 01-2014.

Answer (score 0):

This should work as expected, might not be fast but should give the correct results.

Basically it's all work from Table1 that was done in Feb and then removing all work that was scheduled in Feb (any of it's schedules)

```
SELECT Work_ID 
  FROM Table1
 WHERE MONTH(Actual_Work_Date) = 2
   AND Work_ID NOT IN (SELECT Work_ID 
                         FROM Table2
                        WHERE MONTH(Scheduled_Date) = 2)
```

Comment: I tried using this way, it also shows Work_ID 10001. Maybe because Work_ID 10001 also scheduled on 2014-01-22 which is not in this month (02-2014)?

Comment: I revised my answer, I think I understand now what you asked :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the syntax of MySQL, but this may help.

```
SELECT 
    a.*
FROM Table a
INNER JOIN Table b ON a.Work_id = b.Work_id
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(a.Actual_Work_Date,"%c") = your_month_number AND DATE_FORMAT(b.Scheduled_Date,"%c") <> your_month_number AND a.Work_id = 10000
```

Use this link for more about datetime functions.
[MySQL DateTime Function](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-date-time-functions.htm)

Comment: I cannot use "WHERE a.Work_ID = 10000", because there are a lot more Work_ID with same condition as Work_ID 10000.

Comment: Then you can use Work_ID <> 10001 in WHERE condition if you want to have records except 10001.

Comment: Unfortunately, there are also a lot of Work_ID with same condition as Work_ID 10001.

Comment: Even this should work. Okay, can you describe what actually you are looking for?